# Duplication of desktop in two screens do not work

Tags: intel, nvidia, desktop, hdmi

I have laptop dell latitude e6430 which come with 2 graphic cards one is integrated intel hd graphics card 4000 hd and the second is nvidia nvs 5200m .When i connect laptop to tv screen with hdmi cable
,i face a problem that duplication of desktop do not work (the tv screen still black and show me message that is no signal) Although I am absolutely sure that the cable is intact and so is the screen

Comment: Maybe the second graphic card must be enabled from the BIOS..

Comment: do you know how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the input on tv to hdmi and the correct hdmi port number